# Html parsing using jsoup, with serialized output

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

could you help me with a little problem with JSOUP,
My problem goes like.....

The source html code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p class="needed-header">Needed Header</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 1</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
<p class="not-needed-text">Not-Needed Text</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 2</p>
<p class="not-needed-text">Not-Needed Text</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Required Result:Serially as they have been aligned, in the actual html code

```
<p class="needed">Needed Header</p>
<p class="needed">Needed Sub Header 1</p>
<p class="needed">Needed Text</p>
<p class="needed">Needed Sub Header 2</p>
<p class="needed">Needed Text</p>
```

My Code Output: Not serialized, yes i know my sout is the reason they are printed that way, but since the getByElement.. methods pull the respective classes together, how can i get the serialized result

```
<p class="needed-header">Needed Header</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 1</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 2</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
```

Here goes my jsoup code:

```
package parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class InitParserSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitParserSimple ip = new InitParserSimple();
        ip.obtainHtmlFromSource();
        ip.parseUsingElement();
    }

    private String htmlToParse = "";

    public void parseUsingElement() {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlToParse);
        Element chapterBody = doc.body();
        Elements chapterFirstHeader = chapterBody
                .getElementsByClass("needed-header");
        Elements chapterSubHeader = chapterBody
                .getElementsByClass("needed-sub-header");
        Elements chapterParagraphs = chapterBody
                .getElementsByClass("needed-text");
        System.out.println(chapterFirstHeader + "\n"+chapterSubHeader +"\n"+ chapterParagraphs);
    }

    public void obtainHtmlFromSource() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(
                            "E:\\mandeep\\apps\\workspace\\HarrisonParser\\parse_source\\simple_parse.psrc"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                htmlToParse = htmlToParse + sCurrentLine;

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't quite undersatnd what you want. Maybe this? Elements els = doc.select("p:contains(needed)");

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov I suspect that OP has problem with order of elements. It probably should be `Header->SubHearer->text->AnotherSubHeader->text` while it is `Header->SubHearer->SubHearer->text->text`

Comment: Maybe this? Elements els = doc.select("p[class^=needed]"); I made a mistake first time, now you'll get all p tags that class attribute starts with 'needed' in original order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your classes are not really named with `needed...` you can create list of elements you want to find using comma `,` like

```
File myHtmlFile = new File("input.txt");
String htmlToParse = new Scanner(myHtmlFile).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlToParse);
Element chapterBody = doc.body();

Elements allElements = chapterBody
        .select("p.needed-header, p.needed-sub-header, p.needed-text");
for (Element el : allElements)
    System.out.println(el);
```

Output:

```
<p class="needed-header">Needed Header</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 1</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
<p class="needed-sub-header">Needed Sub Header 2</p>
<p class="needed-text">Needed Text</p>
```

---

Also assuming that you will want to add some logic based of element class you can just test what type of element you are handling with `el.className()` like

```
for (Element el : allElements) {
    if (el.className().equals("needed-header")) {
        System.out.println(">>>>" + el.text() + "<<<<");
    } else if (el.className().equals("needed-sub-header")) {
        System.out.println(">>" + el.text() + "<<");
    } else{
        System.out.println(el.text());
    }
}
```

output:

```
>>>>Needed Header<<<<
>>Needed Sub Header 1<<
Needed Text
>>Needed Sub Header 2<<
Needed Text
```